# How to disable a button on AppShell, Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-shell

I have on my AppShell, 3 ShellContent and my problem is that when I am in the second page or third or... in my route if I click on the ShellContent of my route it takes me back to the first page I would like to disable my button when I am on the same route, I don't have this problem on UWP, just on iOS, do you have an idea ?

I already tried IsEnabled="False", but it ignored it.

Here's a pic of my AppShell

[image: AppShell]

and here's my code

```
 <TabBar>

    <ShellContent x:Name="BureauShell" Title="Bureau" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ViewLogin}" Icon="office-desk.png"/>
    <ShellContent x:Name="ServicesShell" Title="Services" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ViewMenu}" Icon="booking.png"/>
    <ShellContent x:Name="PiecesShell" Title="Batiment" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ViewChat}" Icon="building.png" />
    
</TabBar>
```

Comment: ```if I click on the ShellContent of my route it takes me back to the first page``` Could you please elaborate more about this? Did you mean clicking on the bottom tabbar then it backs to first page?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I have a login page at first then I push to "bureau" and if I click on the bottom tabbar it takes me back to my login page

Comment: That's weird. Though I am not sure if I understand correctly. You have a login page, then you navigation to the Shell which contains three other pages (ViewLogin, ViewMenu, ViewChat ). Then you click one of the three items in shell tabbar, it navigations back to login page?

Comment: No, my Login (ViewLogin) page is in the same shell that my bureau (ViewBureau) page, and when I am in my bureau and I click on my shell BureauShell it takes me back to the login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation can be canceled by invoking the Cancel method on the ShellNavigatingEventArgs object. Consider adding the following code in AppShell.cs:

```
    protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigating(args);

        if(args.Current!=null)
        {
            if (args.Target.Location == args.Current.Location)
            {
                //You could add more logic
                Console.WriteLine("123");
                args.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }
```

Using the above code, the Navigation is cancelled if it is on the same route. You may add some more logic according to your case.

For more info, you could refer to [Shell Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#navigation-events)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, it fixes my problem.

Comment: Glad it helps! Happy coding!